# Getting data set in parent component

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vue-router

I used the Vue CLI in order to generate a Vue application. It made two components, `App` and `HelloWorld`.

In my app component I immediately on start calls a thid party service in order to setup some stuff (like getting a token) for calls from other components. However I want to share the data inside the `App.vue` component to all its child since it is the template of the application.

How can I achieve this? What is the correct way of thinking here? Should I write some kind of service that stores the specific data I want so I can access that service from all other components?

This is how I access the token in `App.vue`:

```
methods: {
    fetchToken: function () {
      const url = this.baseUrl + this.tokenUrl
      fetch(url, {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + this.subKey
        }
      })
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(json => {
          console.log('Getting token..', json.data)
          this.token = json.data
          this.token.created = new Date()
        })
    }
  },


<template>
  <div id="app">
    <router-view/>
  </div>
</template>
```

This is how the template code looks in the `App.vue`, since I use Vue-router it displays the correct component on the index page.

In the `App.vue` I can simply do `this.token` to access the data, but in the other component I of course get `: Property or method "token" is not defined on the instance` because the property is not defined in that component.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The correct way to store that token is storing it globally. You should use [vuex](https://vuex.vuejs.org)

Comment: Thanks I will look into that!

Comment: Look at Vuex, but for some folk it will be a sledgehammer to crack a nut. But you really should [use a store for page state](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/state-management.html). Try and keep state out of Vue components. Try and use data when you can, and props when you must.